Receiving White Pages in PHP from GitHub database despite browser retrieving files
I added this repo after following the provided instructions, I successfully installed the database on my website. However, although my browser locates all the files, it only displays white pages upon loading. As I am relatively new to coding, I am uncertain about how to begin addressing this issue. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
repo
:  https://github.com/rbiddle/phppickem?tab=readme-ov-file#readme
I have verified the HTML tags where anticipated, and have included additional text outside the HTML body, which is displayed.

A github repo is not normally used as a webserver. It's a place to store your files for development, you deploy them to your actual webserver for actual users.

Are you deploying a static or dynamic website like Joomla or Wordpress? If so then perhaps your database isnt connected yet, that is a common problem, or your htaccess is causing trouble. We need a bit more info please, what kind of site and db are you deploying?

I have uploaded the files to my website with is hosted through Godaddy

my site is on Godaddy and I'm not using Joomla or woorpress. after running the install I checked adminmySQL and there were a bunch of new files? also got a connected message

If you just get white pages, check the php error log for problems

You should first check whether this runs on your local machine. Make sure you have a webserver (of your choice) installed, which could be Apache, Nginx, IIS, whatever. Make sure that you can load
http://localhost

or
https://localhost

If there is an index.html there, then create helloworld.html with some simplistic content, you can inspire from https://www.learn-html.org/en/Hello%2C_World%21 for example.
Make sure that works. If so, check whether PHP is installed on your machine. If not, install it. Then create a foo.php besides your helloworld.html with this content
<?php

echo "hello world";

try loading
http://localhost/foo.php

and check whether it displays hello world. If so, you are on the right track. If not, then make sure PHP is allowed by your local webserver.
When foo.php works, download your repo and test it. If it works, then you've reached a big milestone. If not, then you have an issue with the repo itself, watch out for PHP errors and fix them.
Once you have fixed everything, set up a local virtual host and make sure it works properly.
Then, if you want to host it on a remote server, then you can be confident about the repo being operational, so make sure you own the domain you want to use, ssh to the server and set up the webserver and host configs and PHP there too, just like you did on your local machine, with the obvious possible differences between operating systems.
